# DisplayNameFor - I have a View model and i;m not sure how to implement with that

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view model:

```
public class SitesListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view:

```
@model .....WebUI.Models.SitesListViewModel

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th width="100%">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Sites)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.EditButton("Edit", Url.Action("Edit", new { siteID = item.SiteID }), new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ViewButton("View", Url.Action("Details", new { siteID = item.SiteID }), new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })</td>
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Site"))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("siteID", item.SiteID)
                    @Html.DeleteButton("Delete", new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

this line needs to know that it is working on the Model.Sites.Name rather than just model.Name.. how do I do this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
```

?

I imagined it would be something like:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sites.Name)
```

but it doesn't work:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<>` indead of a `IEnumerable<>` in your viewmodel and a `for` loop should do the trick.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Sites.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Sites[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditButton("Edit", Url.Action("Edit", new { siteID = Model.Sites[i].SiteID }), new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })</td>
        <td>@Html.ViewButton("View", Url.Action("Details", new { siteID = Model.Sites[i].SiteID }), new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })</td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Site"))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("siteID", Model.Sites[i].SiteID)
                @Html.DeleteButton("Delete", new ButtonRequirement { ExtraClasses = "btn-xs" })
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```